# what method should I use for putting rubber bands on wheels?

Tags: wheeled-robot

I have a BOE bot PBasic2 stamp based robot that came with rubberband "tires" for the wheel. however, they are very tight and I can't figure out how to get them onto the plastic hubs.
the furthest I've gotton was mostly covering the outside, but when trying to make it less crooked it came off again.
is there some trick to getting those pesky tires to stay on?

Answer (score 1):

A BOE wheel is shown below.

[image: boe wheel]

To get the tire (the outer rubber ring) onto the wheel, pulling a thin string around between the wheel and tire might work.  However, you might also try slightly heating the ring (eg, with a hair dryer), which is likely to make the ring slightly more flexible and stretchy.  Be careful not to overheat the ring.  Uncontrolled hot air from a heat gun probably is too warm and would risk melting the ring.

Comment: Perhaps a thin screwdriver wedged between the tire and wheel might help.